# Redirect request based on user agent

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I need to redirect the user based on the Useragent.

Currently my WordPress site using ajax based theme. So the URL format is

```
http://www.example.com/#!/my_first_post/
```

My current htaccess code is as follows.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is what I need help to do:

```
if (user agent == "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" ){
 redirect the url without hashes
 ex:http://www.example.com/my_first_post/
}
```

I need to do this using htaccess.

Comment: Hashbangs... Yuck... http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a mod_rewrite variable to detect user-agents:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/1\.1 [NC]
```

but it's not going to help you. There is no way you can match a URL fragment in your htaccess file because the fragment *is never sent to the server*. URL fragments are completely on the client side, so you're best bet is to add some modifications to your theme to do the user agent check and have it not use fragments if it's from facebook.